# How to edit _generated_background_page.html page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to edit `_generated_background_page.html` in chrome extension? I would like to put more js files there as modules, so it wont be everything in `background.js`

I saw extensions like this, but how they did that?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxc9V.png)

They even add iframes in background page... But how?

Comment: Simply add the scripts in "scripts" array, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages#manifest).

Comment: Okay, but how they add other code to background page? Here example with iframe - https://i.imgur.com/NIoA0g8.png

Comment: It's just like any other page so use the standard DOM methods like document.createElement and appendChild.

Comment: Or you can declare `"page": "bgpage.html"` instead of "scripts".